# How to get page meta (title, description, images) like facebook attach url using Regex in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
using WebClient client = new WebClient();

var data = client.DownloadString(url);
```

then using Regex to retrieve metadata (title, description, images) like facebook url attach, but I don't know how to write Regex.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of regex. [**Explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please put the code if you have done it. I am bit confused with HTML Agility pack, as i am not able to find an example where i can simply extra title, description & give user choice to select and image from a particular URL